# I build a system that collect data from user like Google analytics- Which dev. skill should i need for that?

Tags: google-analytics

I need to know how to develop a google analytics server side.

I am building a system that collect data from user by extension chrome and show this data to other customer. The data i need to store (part like google)
•   User language 
•   Time on item
•   Browser & OS
•   Real-Time Users at item
•   New vs Returning
•   Users Flow

and much more that google don't have.
What are the skills i need to search for the developer?
PHP? Java? etc?
i will be happy to get some directions.
sorry for my english...

Comment: This is much to broad to answer (and if you have to ask that question it'S probably to ambitious a goal in any case), but this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30522981/send-analytic-data-to-different-domain-without-response/30523863#30523863 might provide at least a little guidance.

Answer (score 0):

The Google Analytics API has [client libraries](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/) in many different languages.

The [Hello Analytics API](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v3/quickstart/service-py) examples will take you through the steps to build a simple application.